# wrapRootElement + contextAPI : Page changes cause provider to re-render therefore resetting state

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, react-context

### Summary

I am using React context api and hooks to create a global 'StateProvider' however when I change pages my provider re-renders causing me to loose the active state and return to the default.

It is my understanding that using the wrapRootElement method should mean that my stateProvider should persist.

Some advice on how I can debug this issue would be greatly appreciated!

### Relevant information

gatsby-browser.js

```js
const StateProvider = require("./src/components/store/store").StateProvider
exports.wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => {
  return <StateProvider>{element}</StateProvider>
}
```

store.js

```js
const StateProviderContext = createContext()
const DispatchProviderContext = createContext()

const StateProvider = ({ children }) => {
  console.log("init")
  const tocTree = useEntries()
  const initialState = reducer(
    {},
    {
      type: INIT_PAGE,
      value: { pathname, tocTree },
    }
  )
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)
  return (
    <StateProviderContext.Provider value={state}>
      <DispatchProviderContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
        {children}
      </DispatchProviderContext.Provider>
    </StateProviderContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: `StateProvider` is not being exported. Could that be the issue?

Comment: @PaulBunker I'm having the same issue with Gatsby. Did you solve the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*Follow along*: https://codesandbox.io/s/soanswer60606158-pfm2b

Normally you need to implement `wrapRootElement` in both `gatsby-ssr.js` AND `gatsby-browser.js`.

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-apis/#wrapRootElement

[image: wrapRootElement note]

You can see that I extracted out `wrapRootElement.js`, which is imported in both files mentioned.

`./wrapRootElement.js`

```
import React from "react"
import StateProvider from "./src/components/store/store"

const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => {
  return <StateProvider>{element}</StateProvider>
}

export default wrapRootElement
```

`gatsby-browser.js`

```
import wrapRootElement from "./wrapRootElement"

export { wrapRootElement }
```

`gatsby-ssr.js`

```
import wrapRootElement from "./wrapRootElement"

export { wrapRootElement }
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem; The state was getting reset after changing the pages. The point that solved my problem was that you should use the Gatsby's `<Link>` to change the page (I was using a `<a>` tag before).

And my code now works perfectly without needing a `gatsby-ssr.js`.